# How to use count() in Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am assisting a project which uses flask-sqlalchemy.
I would like a db query to count the number of records in the table.

Can I use `table.query.filter_by(condition).count()` directly?
Or is there anything that I need to add?

Please assist me. I am a begineer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49):

None of the given answers address *flask-sqlalchemy* specifically, where you would use exactly the example you gave:

```
Table.query.filter_by(condition).count()
```

You can perform `.count()` without filters:

```
Table.query.count()
```

You can also count using M2M relationships:

```
ParentTable.children.count()
```

And you can use any of these directly in your jinja templates like:

```
{{ Table.query.filter_by(condition).count() }}
```

Bonus points (for the performance minded):

`.count()` is a bit slow (especially with MySQL, thanks to a poor handling of subqueries), so instead, you can use a custom count that looks like this:

```
db.session.execute(Table.query.filter_by(condition).statement.with_only_columns([func.count()]).order_by(None)).scalar()
```

That's assuming `db` is your SQLAlchemy instance (ie, `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`).  It's a mouthful, but it will save you a little bit of overhead on big queries.

Comment: This is the real answer and provides an excellent example with jinja templates also.  Thank you

Comment: Do NOT use .count with Postgres:

`Table.query.filter_by(condition).count()` produces:
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_1 FROM (
  SELECT table.field1, table.field2, ... table.fieldN
   WHERE condition) AS anon_1`

`count` in postgres is bad to start with (because of MVC postgres does not keep row counts of tables), but doing it in a subquery triggers the worst-case scenario regularly. Also notice how SQL Alchemy fetches every row in the table to pass to count...

Better to use: `db.session.query(db.func.count()).filter(condition).scalar()`

Answer (score 30):

Per [this source](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#counting), the following should work for you:

```
session.query(Class_name).filter_by(condition).count()
```

Class_name is the name of the mapped class for your table.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that. But remember, that `count()` uses one more query, like this:

```
Select count(q.*) from (select * from table) q
```

However, you can make it more efficient by using only one query. You can use this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func
number = session.query(func.count(table.id).label('number').first().number
```

The SQL query will be like this:

```
Select count(table.id) as number from table
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: SQLAlchemy 2.0**

In SQLAlchemy 2.0, the use of the query object has been deprecated [SQLAlchemy 2.0 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/index.html#orm-querying-guide). The following code has worked for me (adapted to the OP's question):

```
with app.app_context():
        my_query = db.func.count(Table.id)
        number = db.session.execute(my_query).scalar()
```

In the above, Table.id could also be substituted by a condition; e.g., in my specific case, using class Cafe(), I used the condition: Cafe.location == "Peckham". A suitable condition to be used in the OP's case would depend on the Table class.

Answer (score -1):

Simple is best:

```
accounts = db.session.execute('select count(id) as c from user').scalar()
```

Comment: The OP specifically asks how do it using an ORM and not raw SQL